# C - Unable to find memory leak

Tags: c, matrix, memory, memory-leaks, allocation

We are to do matrix operations for school and I have a memory leak somewhere when freeing matrixes.
I have been searching for the leak for a few hours now and still cannot find it. The problem is probably somewhere between freeing matrixes during calculating operation.

stdin:

1 2 (number of rows and columns)

6 4 (matrix values)

+

1 2

-6 7

+

1 2

-6 -4

Valgrind:

```
==1480== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1480==     in use at exit: 56 bytes in 3 blocks
==1480==   total heap usage: 17 allocs, 14 frees, 8,472 bytes allocated
==1480==
==1480== 56 (32 direct, 24 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 3
==1480==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1480==    by 0x400812: make_matrix (main.c:42)
==1480==    by 0x400AFA: calculate_operation (main.c:97)
==1480==    by 0x4010BE: main (main.c:193)
==1480==
==1480== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1480==    definitely lost: 32 bytes in 1 blocks
==1480==    indirectly lost: 24 bytes in 2 blocks
==1480==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1480==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1480==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

My code (Ignore stderr messages, they are in czech.)

- only included important parts

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define POINTERSIZE 8
#define MAXMATRIXES 100

typedef struct
{
  int row_count, column_count;
  int **values;
} Matrix;

void free_matrix(Matrix *matrix)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < matrix->row_count; i++)
  {
    free(matrix->values[i]);
  }
  free(matrix->values);
  free(matrix);
}

Matrix *make_matrix(int row_count, int column_count)
{
  Matrix *matrix = malloc(column_count * row_count * 2 * POINTERSIZE); ***(PROBLEM HERE)***
  matrix->row_count = row_count;
  matrix->column_count = column_count;
  matrix->values = malloc(column_count * row_count * POINTERSIZE);
  for (int i = 0; i < row_count; i++)
  {
    matrix->values[i] = malloc(column_count * sizeof(int));
  }
  return matrix;
}

Matrix *calculate_operation(Matrix *matrix1, Matrix *matrix2, char operator)
{
  if (is_operation_possible(matrix1, matrix2, operator) != 1)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Chybny vstup!\n");
    free_matrix(matrix1);
    free_matrix(matrix2);
    exit(100);
  }
  Matrix *result;
  switch (operator)
  {
  case '+':
    result = make_matrix(matrix1->row_count, matrix1->column_count); ***(PROBLEM HERE)***
    for (int i = 0; i < result->row_count; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < result->column_count; j++)
      {
        result->values[i][j] = matrix1->values[i][j] + matrix2->values[i][j];
      }
    }
    break;
}

Matrix *load_matrix()
{
  int row_count, column_count, input_check;
  input_check = scanf("%d %d", &row_count, &column_count);
  if (input_check != 2 || row_count <= 0 || column_count <= 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Chybny vstup!\n");
    exit(100);
  }
  Matrix *matrix = make_matrix(row_count, column_count);
  fill_matrix(matrix, row_count, column_count);
  return matrix;
}

void adjust_matrixes(Matrix *matrixes[], char operators[])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < MAXMATRIXES; i++)
  {
    while (operators[i] == '*' && operators[i + 1])
    {
      matrixes[i] = calculate_operation(matrixes[i], matrixes[i + 1], '*');
      free_matrix(matrixes[i + 1]);
      operators[i] = operators[i + 1];
      for (int j = i + 1; j < MAXMATRIXES - 1; j++)
      {
        matrixes[j] = matrixes[j + 1];
        operators[j] = operators[j + 1];
      }
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char operators[MAXMATRIXES];
  for (int i = 0; i < MAXMATRIXES; i++)
  {
    operators[i] = 0;
  }

  Matrix *matrixes[MAXMATRIXES];
  for (int i = 0; i < MAXMATRIXES; i++)
  {
    matrixes[i] = load_matrix();
    scanf(" %c", &operators[i]);

    if (operators[i] != '+' && operators[i] != '-' && operators[i] != '*')
    {
      operators[i] = 0;
      break;
    }
  }
  adjust_matrixes(matrixes, operators);
  int index = 0;
  Matrix *result = matrixes[index];
  while (operators[index] != 0)
  {
    result = calculate_operation(result, matrixes[index + 1], operators[index]); ***(PROBLEM HERE)***
    free_matrix(matrixes[index]);
    index++;
  }
  free_matrix(matrixes[index]);
  print_matrix(result);
  free_matrix(result);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please label the lines mentioned in the messages, I do not want to count.

Answer (score 1):

You have problems/errors in the sizes you are giving to allocated memory blocks in your `make_matrix` function. See the annotations and suggested corrections in the following code:

```c
Matrix *make_matrix(int row_count, int column_count)
{
//  Matrix *matrix = malloc(column_count * row_count * 2 * POINTERSIZE);
    Matrix *matrix = malloc(sizeof(Matrix)); // enough memory to hold 1 "Matrix"
    matrix->row_count = row_count;
    matrix->column_count = column_count;
//  matrix->values = malloc(column_count * row_count * POINTERSIZE);
    matrix->values = malloc(row_count * POINTERSIZE); // One pointer for EACH ROW ONLY
    for (int i = 0; i < row_count; i++)
    {
        matrix->values[i] = malloc(column_count * sizeof(int));
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

Another problem (the likely cause of the leaks) is that you are not freeing the `result` memory on most of the runs through the `while` loop at the end of your `main`. One way of getting round this is to use a second pointer for the first argument of the `calculate_operation` function, setting this up to its initial value before the loop, then updating it to the latest `result` on each run through:

```c
//...
int index = 0;
Matrix* param1 = matrixes[index]; //Use "param1" as the first operand pointer
Matrix* result = NULL; // This will ONLY be used for the result
while (operators[index] != 0)
{
    result = calculate_operation(param1, matrixes[index + 1], operators[index]);
    if (index != 0) free_matrix(param1);// On first loop, param1 is freed below...
    free_matrix(matrixes[index]);       // ...because it is set to matrixes[0]
    param1 = result; // We set "param1" to point to the result of the calculation.
    index++;
}
free_matrix(matrixes[index]);
if (result != NULL) { // Just in case the loop never ran!
    print_matrix(result);
    free_matrix(result);
}
return 0;
```

Comment: I am still getting the same errors, only the amount of memory lost changed (Due to changed sizes of malloced blocks). But your changes make the code more elegant and logical, thanks!

Comment: The while loop stops in due time, because if not, I would get wrong results from the operation itself. All the test examples from my teacher work well and the results are right. The "only" problem is with the memory.

Comment: I thought that if I rewrite the `result` each time when going through the `while` loop, then freeing the `result` only once at the end of `main` is ok. Is this wrong? Should I free the result somehow each time when going through the `while` loop? I was not able to find an answer for this.

Comment: @JanBorecký Yes, absolutely! When you create a new memory chunk and just assign its address to a pointer that **already is a pointer** to another chunk, then that "earlier" chunk is leaked, as you then will have no pointer to it.

Comment: That might be the answer! I am not sure how to write it in my code though. Do you have any idea for that?

Comment: @adrian-reinstate-monica I wrote `free_matrix(param1);` instead of `free(param1)` and it works with no leaks. I tried another test examples, and there are still one or more leaks though.

Comment: @JanBorecký Aha! You spotted my (cough) 'deliberate' error!  Well done! (I've now fixed it in the posted answer, too.) Time for me to hit the sack, here in the UK. Maybe give some details on the other test and I'll have a look come the light of morning.

Answer (score 0):

The problems were in freeing during adjust_matrixes and at the end of main, where freeing is quite tricky. With big help from @adrian-reinstate-monica (Thank you very much. :)) I managed to fix these parts of the code.

```
void adjust_matrixes(Matrix *matrixes[], char operators[])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < MAXMATRIXES; i++)
  {
    Matrix *param1 = matrixes[i];
    while (operators[i] == '*' && operators[1])
    {
      matrixes[i] = calculate_operation(param1, matrixes[i + 1], '*');
      free_matrix(param1);
      param1 = matrixes[i];
      free_matrix(matrixes[i + 1]);
      //Shifting next operator to the position
      //of current operator, so that
      //while loop won't repeat forever.
      operators[i] = operators[i + 1];
      //Shifting every matrix & operator behind current ones
      //one step closer.
      for (int j = i + 1; j < MAXMATRIXES - 1; j++)
      {
        matrixes[j] = matrixes[j + 1];
        operators[j] = operators[j + 1];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char operators[MAXMATRIXES];
  for (int i = 0; i < MAXMATRIXES; i++)
  {
    operators[i] = 0;
  }

  Matrix *matrixes[MAXMATRIXES];
  //Scanning matrixes and operators from stdin.
  for (int i = 0; i < MAXMATRIXES; i++)
  {
    matrixes[i] = load_matrix();
    scanf(" %c", &operators[i]);

    if (operators[i] != '+' && operators[i] != '-' && operators[i] != '*')
    {
      operators[i] = 0;
      break;
    }
  }

  adjust_matrixes(matrixes, operators);

  //The calculations themselves in
  //adjusted array of matrixes
  int index = 0;
  Matrix *param1 = matrixes[index];
  Matrix *result = NULL;
  while (operators[index] != 0)
  {
    result = calculate_operation(param1, matrixes[index + 1], operators[index]);
    if (index != 0)
      free_matrix(param1);
    free_matrix(matrixes[index]);
    param1 = result;
    index++;
  }
  free_matrix(matrixes[index]);
  print_matrix(result);
  free_matrix(result);
  return 0;
}
```

With these edited, everything works.